# Single Sign on WCF problems

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, single-sign-on

I'm developing a Client and Server side application in .NET. There are alot of clients which will contact and use one server. Inbetween the client and the server, a Single Sign on functionality is added, which I have no control over, not source code and configuration options. To pass this single sign on, a `HttpModule` is specific and configured correctly in `IIS` and the `web.config`. The problem I'm facing is due to timeouts. When the users are inactive, which means no server calls had been made within a span of ~5 minutes, the connection will timeout and no "new login prompt" is being displayed.

This  Single Sign-on portal was primarly build for `ASP.NET` applications, and the web browser will handle all of the cookie related stuff, I guess.

After some time browsing, I came over the topic [WCF Instance Management](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/86007/ways-to-do-WCF-instance-management-Per-call-Per). As I use `wsHttpBinding` with `Transport` as Security, the default instancing mode is `perSession`.

Does anybody experience such problem? How did you solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify please. Which *new login prompt* are you expecting to be displayed. What makes you think instancing mode is the problem here? If there are no active clients for 5 minutes, whose connection is timing out?

Comment: @TomRedfern The "New login Prompt" is a functionality in a  thirdparty application, where the users has to enter a pin code. I just thought it had to be with instancing mode, as other applications which is written i ASP.NET doesn't have the same problem, due to the cookie handling. It might not be a timeout problem, the only problem is that the user is not prompted to reenter the password, as this should be stored in a cookie somehow. All of the other applications works due to the cookie handling, they say. That is basically all the information I've been given.